# How does 'self' exactly work in inherited classes?

Tags: php, inheritance

According to php, class::self always points to the class itself, but as I wrote down these codes, something strange happens:

```
class C_foo{
    function foo() { return "foo() from C_foo"; }
    function bar() { echo self::foo(); }
}

class C_bar extends C_foo{
    function foo() { return "foo() from C_bar"; }
}

C_foo::bar();
C_bar::bar();
```

I thought the output would have been:

```
foo() from C_foo
foo() from C_bar
```

But in fact:

```
foo() from C_foo
foo() from C_foo
```

It means that the *self* in parent class does NOT exactly inherit into the child, it works more like to this:

```
foo() {return parent::foo();}
```

Is that a feature from php or is it a bug? Or is it mean to be like this?

Otherwise, such thing is occurred as I tried to tell a class create objects from itself, the code is something like this:

```
class Models {
    function find($exp) {
        ...
        ...

        $temp_model = new self();
        ...
        ...
    }
}

class Something extends Models {...}

$somethings = Something::find("...");
```

Maybe someone would ask, "why don't you set a variable with the value of **class**, and use the variable as the __construction function?"

Like this:

```
...
...
function find($exp) {
    ...
    ...
    $class_name = __class__;
    $temp_model = new $class_name();
    ...
    ...
}
...
```

In fact I did that, and got a even more weird result:

It works only when the class does not have any property or function but `find()`, or an error telling me a variable shows off where a function sould exist would jump out.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In PHP, classes are not object. Because of that, there is no inheritance of static methods (actually, they are similar to global functions).

So, when C_foo says self, it always means C_foo (even if you called a method from C_bar).

If you want create instances from an abstract class method, you should try the Factory pattern.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try the Factory pattern :)

Answer (score 41):

It sounds like you're describing the PHP feature known as 'late static binding'.

PHP provides two syntaxes: `self::` and `static::`.

`static` was introduced in PHP 5.3 because a lot of people expected `self` to work the you're describing.

See the PHP manual for more: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

You can also use the syntax `new self()` or `new static()` to create new instances:

```
$parent = new self();
$child = new static();
```

Comment: Edited to add the syntax `new xxx()`in addition to `xxx::`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the class which receives the methods of the parent is of that class. So:

$bar is Bar, therefore self:: refers to Bar, not to Foo. Even though that method is from Foo.

This may be different from Java, but it probably indicates how PHP is doing inheritance internally.

Comment: I'm now trying to change my code, and may be I really need to go deeper into this language, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, php thinks about inheritence differently. It's less a 'stack' and more of a 'merge'.