# Under what conditions does PHP 7's self refer to the base class?

Tags: php, inheritance, php-7

As noted [on Reddit's LOL PHP sub](https://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/comments/5zgur6/q_does_selfsome_const_refer_to_the_current_class/), PHP 7 may use either the extended class or the base class when referring to `self`, in contrast to PHP 5 which always refers to the extended class.

```
<?php

class Foo {
    const A = "FooA";
    const B = self::A . self::C;
    const C = "FooC";

}

class Bar extends Foo {
    const A = "BarA";
    const C = "BarC";
}

var_dump(Bar::B);
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/sXiiL#output)

## PHP 5

```
string(8) "BarABarC"
```

## PHP 7

```
string(8) "FooABarC"
```

The behaviour of PHP 7 is particularly worrisome as there does not seem to be any simple rule to know when `self` refers to the base class or the extended class. **What are rules for determining to which class `self` will refer in PHP 7?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131786/how-does-self-exactly-work-in-inherited-classes

Comment: It seems from the posted 3v7l link that there was a shift in behaviour (I'm not able to find any reasoning though) between PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 and also a bug in PHP from version 7.0.0 to 7.1.3... Probably best to avoid such constructs...

Comment: It depends on where B is defined. Move the definition of B around and check the output.  If you move to the bottom the outputs for all 7.x.x versions are the same. Move it to the top and you notice a difference.

Comment: Also see what happens when you replace `self::` with `parent::`: [https://3v4l.org/tr3Nv](https://3v4l.org/tr3Nv)

Comment: My personal opinion is `Foo`'s reference to `self::C` should throw a warning because it's dynamically referencing a constant before it's defined.  However the interpreter chooses to handle it, coding something this way in a real-world application is a bad idea.

Comment: @MattS: Your comment does seem to describe a rule for determining to which class `self` will refer in PHP 7. You might want to expand that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self::` *should* always refer to the class it is used in (note that PHP 5's behavior is wrong too.)

This was a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69676), [fixed](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/2bba4a0d7f6d5e5712d60bc1cf2119622d837e55) in [7.1.4](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.1.4), that applied to resolution of `self::` and `parent::` only within class constants.

Basically in:

```
const B = self::A . self::C;
```

`self::C` is still unknown at this point and resolution is deferred. At the point of eventual resolution the proper scope was unfortunately lost.

---

The problem is also more subtle than simply base vs extended as you can end up with a value from a *different* extending class. E.g.:

https://3v4l.org/cY1I0

```
class A {
    const selfN = self::N;
    const N = 'A';
}

class B extends A {
    const N = 'B';
}

class C extends A {
    const N = 'C';
}

var_dump(B::selfN); // A

var_dump(C::selfN); // A
```

In PHP 7.0.0 through 7.1.3 this outputs:

```
string(1) "B"
string(1) "B"
```

Though if you swap it for:

https://3v4l.org/RltQj

```
var_dump(C::selfN); // A

var_dump(B::selfN); // A
```

You'll get:

```
string(1) "C"
string(1) "C"
```

---

To avoid this in affected versions use the class name rather than `self::` in class constant definitions, e.g. `const selfN = A::N`

Answer (score 2):

The expected behavior outlined in this example is undefined.  `Foo`'s reference to `self::C` is dynamically referencing a constant before it's been defined.  If you were to execute `Foo::B` I would expect it to throw a warning.

For more context, see this "not a bug" [bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72916):

> LSB works by storing the class named in the last "non-forwarding call"
>   so the key here is to understand what a forwarding call is: A "forwarding call" is a static one that is introduced by self::, parent::, static::.
>
> LSB and its forwarded call tracking are separate mechanisms from class resolution done through ::. When you use self::method() or static::method() the LSB class is unchanged, however the two will (potentially) resolve to and call different method()s.
>   In other words, the internal state is the same but the actual code being executed next differs

However the interpreter chooses to handle it, coding something this way in a real-world application is a probably bad idea.